# In hadoop how do you print within the "configure()" method?

Tags: hadoop, configure, mapper

In the bottom example in this hadoop tutorial there is a "configure()" method.
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Source+Code-N10FD0

I wanted to put a print statement within it to know that it arrives there. However, nothing prints to console. Am I doing it wrong or is there something to hadoop that I do not understand.

It is on line 28 of the example at the bottom of the page.

Here is what I put, but again only the normal output of WordCount was put to console.

```
public void configure(JobConf job) {
System.out.println("HERE !@#$%^&*");
caseSensitive = job.getBoolean("wordcount.case.sensitive", true);
inputFile = job.get("map.input.file");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say console - do you mean the console from which you submit the job from?

If you're running on local mode, then i would expect the sysout to be in the console.

If this job was run against a cluster (pseudo or real), then the sysout statement will go to the task logs, and will not come back to your local console (unless the task has an error, in which case you will probably see the stdout/err come back to the console). You can view these logs by going to the Job Tracker web UI, and then drill down on the job to display the map and reduce tasks - each task has logs associated with it, which you can view via the web ui too.

Comment: Thank you. That was a good answer. Would you happen to know why a variable would not be changed in the configure method. I set a global int called changeMe. Before running the job I set it to 3 and in the configure I set it to 6. I printed it at the very end inside of the main method. The output was 3.

Comment: Any changes made to the Configuration inside a task attempt is not written back to the global config - a copy is made for each task attempt and you're just updating the copy, rather than the master

Comment: Or are you talking about a global (static) variable inside your mapper / reducer class? In which case the tasks run in a separate JVM and again, these values will never make their way back to the job client where your main is running

Comment: Yeah. I set a static int and changed it from the methods

Comment: Alright, I passed in a value with conf.set("test", "123"); and then in configure said if(Integer.parseInt(job.get("test")) == 123) System.exit(0); and it did indeed fail. Thanks for all the further education.

Answer (score 0):

add this statement to your jobconf object. Ans : conf.set(“mapred.job.tracker”, “local”);